# iCal Time Zone issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, time, icalendar, dday

I'm trying to allow a user to download an iCal for their calendar in ASP.Net, but am having a timezone issue.

If I download the file on my computer, the time appears correct and within the correct timeframe. However, when I try to download it on a phone, the timezone switches and it becomes 5 hours behind (aka 7:00 AM becomes 3:00 AM).

Does anyone know how to fix this issue/set the timezone?

Here is the code:

```
        iCalendar iCal = new iCalendar();

        Event evt = iCal.Create<Event>();

        DateTime dt = (DateTime)Convert.ToDateTime(lblTicketDue.Text);

        Console.Write(dt);

        evt.Start = new iCalDateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);
        evt.End = new iCalDateTime((DateTime)Convert.ToDateTime(lblTicketDue.Text).AddMinutes(15.0));
        Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
        alarm.Action = AlarmAction.Display;
        alarm.Summary = "Ticket due!";
        Trigger t = new Trigger();
        iCalDateTime icdt = new iCalDateTime(dt.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120.0)));
        t.DateTime = icdt;
        alarm.Trigger = t;


        evt.Alarms.Add(alarm);
        iCal.Events.Add(evt);

        iCalendarSerializer serializer = new iCalendarSerializer();
        string output = serializer.SerializeToString(iCal);

        Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
        Response.Write(output);
        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell without looking at the actual iCalendar stream that gets generated but it is quite likely that you are generating your DTSTART/DTEND using floating time (e.g. "20160517T070000" ).
If the event is not recurring (no RRULE), what you want to do is convert your datetime to UTC and use the "date with UTC time" format described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5
i.e. something like "20160517Txx0000Z"

If the event is recurring you would then need to use the last form (date with local time and timezone reference).

Comment: Is the DDay object version of iCalendar not the preferred way of doing things? Should I write to the stream instead?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular API but I would be very surprised if it would not allow you to do what I described above.